# How to stop an execution or set set timeout for an action in AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I'm using aws codepipeline for continues deployment.
In some case, I need to stop an execution (is in progress). 
I tried to search in AWS docs, but seem to doesn't have API for that.

Answer (score 10):

Updated Answer: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/aws-codepipeline-enables-stopping-pipeline-executions/

Original Answer:
* CodePipeline doesn't have an API to stop an execution.
* Workaround: you can stop all executions in the pipeline by updating the pipeline (even a no-op update is fine - you just need to rev the version number).

Comment: I tried to edit the pipeline and it stopped after that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try changing either the stage name (containing the running action) or action name (again the running action). It's insufficient to change an unrelated part of the pipeline (and I didn't make that clear in my original answer).

Comment: Unforuntately this doesn't seem to work if there are no running actions (which can happen if a transition is disabled).

Comment: Did you try changing a stage name, Josh? You can confirm an execution is stopped in the pipeline execution history.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can if you are using `CLI`.

The two CLI commands you should be looking at are `put-job-failure-result` and `put-job-success-result`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/index.html

Comment: I don't think this is what we need. put-job-* was used when you integrate with third party.